# Am I being scammed? [pay off my debts]

Tags: credit-card, scams

I’m talking to someone who wants to pay off my credit cards. He asked which credit cards I have. I told him I didn’t feel comfortable giving out my information. He said he would give me his information and I could just pay it. Is this a scam?

Comment: Pretty much the answer to every question on PM&F that asks, "Is this a scam" is *always* "yes".

Comment: Why does this person want to pay off your credit cards? If you can't answer that, it is definitely a scam. If you CAN answer it, it is PROBABLY a scam.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, sounds a lot like a scam. If something sounds too good to be true, it probably is. Why would a stranger offer to pay off your debt? What is their motivation? It's not *impossible* that a good samaritan wants to help other people, but a criminal motive is far, far more likely, especially since credit card debt scams are fairly common.

It is great that you found this suspicious and disengaged.

If they wanted to help you with your debt, they do not need your credit card numbers. But if you disclosed your card numbers, they might be able to use them for fraudulent transactions – saddling you with more debt.

There are also money laundering concerns. If they provide any payment or access, who says it's their money or account? More likely, it's from a stolen account and they need your help to launder it. A common strategy works like this:

- Scammer promises to give you $2000.
- But you actually receive a transaction for $2500.
- “Oops, that was a mistake”, the scammer says. “Could you please transfer the extra $500 to this other account?”
- You transfer the $500 to the other account.
- Surprise! The original transfer was fraudulent and the $2500 transaction is reversed.
- But your $500 transaction was not fraudulent – you were misled to initiate it, but you authorized the bank to make this transfer.

Result: scammer turned $2000 of stolen funds into $500 of “clean” money, you lost $500 in addition to the debt you already have, and your bank has probably flagged your account as high-risk.

A variant of this scam is that instead of overpaying immediately,
they will ask you to buy them something and that they will reimburse you later in a second payment.
But again, their payments get reversed and you're stuck with the money you spent for the scammer.
It might also be a setup for the “advance fee scam”: they “really” want to pay off your debt, but first they need your help with a comparatively small payment.

On Reddit, [r/Scams has a fairly comprehensive list of common scams, including this “credit card debt scam”](https://www.reddit.com/r/Scams/comments/n00o17/rscams_common_scam_master_post/).